# Error 500 on MySQL PUT and DELETE via Express, Axios

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, redux, axios

I've just inherited a project that was somewhat haphazardly built using tools I'm not very familiar with. It uses Express, Bookshelf, and Axios to access a MySQL database. The Express routes for GET and PUT seem to work just fine, but POST and DELETE each result in an error 500.

Here are the routes I'm using (I've removed many more GET and POST routes that work fine):

```
import express from 'express';
import Points from '../models/points';

let router = express.Router();

// GET all points associated with a specific user AND a specific session
// This works fine.
router.get('/user/:user/session/:session', (req, res) => {
    Points.query({
        select: ['id', 'number', 'quadrant', 'level', 'title', 'category'],
        where: {sessionId: req.params.session, userId: req.params.user}
    }).fetchAll().then(point => {
        res.json({point});
    })
});

// POST a single point to the database.
// This works fine.
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const {sessionId, userId, number, quadrant, level, title, category} = req.body;

    Points.forge({
        sessionId, userId, number, quadrant, level, title, category
    }).save()
        .then(user => res.json({success: true}))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({error: err}));
});

// PUT (update) an existing point
// Doesn't work right now (500)
router.put('/edit/:identifier', (req, res) => {
    Points.update({
        set: {title: req.params.title},
        where: {id: req.params.identifier}
    }), function (err, point) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({message: 'Updated'});
    };
});

// DELETE a point by id
// Doesn't work right now (500)
router.delete('/delete/:identifier', (req, res) => {
    Points.remove({
        id: req.params.identifier
    }), function (err, point) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json({message: 'Deleted'});
        }
    };
});

export default router;
```

And here are the Redux actions that correspond to the routes above:

```
import axios from 'axios';


export function getPointsByUserAndSession(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get('/api/points/user/'+data.user+'/session/'+data.session)
    }
}

export function addPoint(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('/api/points', data)
    }
}

export function editPointById(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.put('/api/points/edit/' + data.id)
    }
}

export function deletePointById(identifier) {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.delete('/api/points/delete/' + identifier)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable CORS with the following code:

```
 router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST,OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH, PUT');
  next();
});
```